# Javascript Countdown Clock: Countdown to every two days

Tags: javascript, timer, clock, countdown, repeat

Does anyone know a Javascript countdown widget that allows me to repeat the countdown every two days. I.E. An event is on Monday, Wednesday, Friday, and Saturday, I want it to count down to those days.

Comment: I didn't understand, do you mean countdown for specific days or countdown for two days from the point it starts?

Also, what have you done until now?

Comment: @matan7890 countdown for two days from the day it starts and then resets. I've trying to develop by modifying the code for the timer from another timer that retrieves the date and time and counts down to the date and time I input, but I'm completely stumpted. The code is too long for me to enter it in here :|

Comment: If you are not asking about a specific programming problem, your question considered as an off topic...